# Handle pytest cases where you want to trigger actions based on pass or fail of a testcase

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am running test cases using pytest; although I would like to collect some logs and zip everything, only if there is a failure

I did write the function that collect logs and zip it, although I can't find a way to actually trigger that for each failed case. I did implement a solution using the `@classmethod` decorators for `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`; but this happen only after all the tests have been ran, and not when a specific test fail.

In each test I run a simple `assertFalse(a < b, "the test did fail"`. I would like to trigger the function that does the log collection only when that condition is actually triggered.

Comment: If you want to start a function directly after the failed assertions, you have to rewrite the assert statement in bytecode, similar to what `pytest` does itself. If you just want to run custom code after a test fails, there's a [recipe for that in `pytest` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no direct way to do it in the `assert` statement, or I was not able to find a way for it.

I just used try-catch and in the `try` I raise an exception,and in the catch code I call the function. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works in my case

```
try:
    if (a < b):
        raise ValueError ("wrong output, collecting logs")
except ValueError:
    # call function to parse logs
    self.parseoutputonerror(a, b, "/tmp/out.zip")
```